How to upgrade openssl version in debian 9?
The openssl version that python3.10+ needs should be greater than 1.1.1? Note PEP-644 which requires OpenSSL >= 1.1. 1 is released in Python 3.10

The openssl version in my debian9 is 1.0.2o. Detail:
➜  which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
➜  openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018

but when I update openssl, It shows me that openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0l-1~deb9u6)
➜ sudo apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openssl is already the newest version (1.1.0l-1~deb9u6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.



So, I wonder how can I update openssl version greater than 1.1.1?

You must run apt-get update first. If it is older than what you want, then you must build and install your OpenSSL manually (it may be pain) or upgrade your OS to newer version. However Debian 9 (Stretch) reachs end of life and unsupported. I suggest upgrading to newer debian 12 or ubuntu 24.04.
